# How to plot the minimum value between 2 columns for each row in a matrix?

Tags: r, plot, histogram, minimum

I have the following table:

```
[1,]    434    359
[2,]   8012   8217
[3,]   1254   1360
[4,]     39    112
[5,]   4322   4199
[6,]    595   2737
[7,]  12984  13112
[8,]   5597   4287
```

I want to plot a histogram of the **smallest** value from each row. I know the hist() function in **R**, but I don't know how to plot only the minimum value between the 2 columns.

Also, I tried installing ggplot2 but it didn't work, so that's not really an option for me.

Comment: You mean the smallest value of each row or of each column ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?pmin`

```
hist(pmin(x[,1], x[,2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
some.table <- cbind(c(434,8012,1254,39,4322,595,12984,5597),c(359,8217,1360,112,4199,2737,13112,4287))
hist(apply(some.table,1,min),breaks=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot the minimum of each row, you don't need to use hist but just a barplot. You have two solution, the standard one and the ggplot one.

The standard one :

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(434,8012,1254,39,4322,595,12984,5597), v2 = c(359,8217,1360,112,4199,2737,13112,4287))
barplot(apply(df,1,min))
```

The ggplot one :

```
library("ggplot2")
df$min <- apply(df, 1, min)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = 1:8, y = min)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

The apply() function applies a statistic to the rows or the columns of a dataframe.